# Oracle SQL - when matched, update AND insert

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I've found some similar questions here, but none of them seemed to actually fit my situation.

The table I'm working on is something like this, it's a table that records students performances on their courses:

```
| STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | ENROLLMENT_TYPE | MARK | STATUS  | VERSION |
|            |           |                 |      |         |         |
| 1234       | 5678      | Mandatory       | 70   | ACTIVE  | 2       |
| 1234       | 5678      | Optional        | 70   | HISTORY | 1       |
| 1234       | 5678      | Optional        | null | HISTORY | 0       |
| 9876       | 4597      | Institutional   | 99   | ACTIVE  | 1       |
| 9876       | 4597      | Institutional   | null | HISTORY | 0       |
```

I need to merge this with another table, that keeps track of the enrollments of students based on their group, so that I can insert or update the rows as needed:

```
| GROUP_ID | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | ENROLLMENT_TYPE |
| 4976555  | 1234       | 5678      | Mandatory       |
| 6399875  | 1234       | 9034      | Optional        |
| 6399875  | 9876       | 4597      | Institutional   |
```

Long story short, I need to check  if the enrollment type is the same or has changed, since some students get enrolled in courses based on the group they're part of, but the groups can change overnight.

All fine until here, but if the rows match, I also need to copy the row I'm about to update and set it as "HISTORY", so that we can keep a record of all the updates that have been made to a certain row.

At the moment, I have a typical

```
MERGE INTO performance USING group_enrollments
ON performance.STUDENT_ID = group_enrollments.STUDENT_ID 
AND performance.COURSE_ID = group_enrollments.COURSE_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ......
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ......
```

The people who worked on this part of code before me thought that it would be a great idea just to copy all the rows as "HISTORY" ones before doing the merge, but this is giving us problems as this procedure runs every night and writes more than 150.000 rows every time.
Any ideas?

16/01 12.34: updated, more info about the tables and their relation

Comment: If I were you, I'd write a query that duplicated the rows you're going to update, so that there was one with an active status and one with a history status - that way you can then use that in your merge statement to insert the historical row and update the active row as appropriate. If you need help with this, please update your question to include data from both of your tables along with the expected output. That way, we can test things out for ourselves.

Comment: Updated for more clarity, I hope.
Thing is, I won't know what rows I have to update until I merge the tables. Do you mean that I should merge them to see what to duplicate and merge them again to update the active rows?

Comment: That helps - thanks! I've added my answer, which shows that I first query to find the rows that need updating, duplicate the necessary rows and then use that query in the merge statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so first off, I would write a query that produced the rows to be updated and/or inserted:

```
WITH    performance AS (SELECT 1234 student_id, 5678 course_id, 'Mandatory' enrollment_type, 70 mark, 'ACTIVE' status, 2 VERSION FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 1234 student_id, 5678 course_id, 'Optional' enrollment_type, 70 mark, 'HISTORY' status, 1 VERSION FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 1234 student_id, 5678 course_id, 'Optional' enrollment_type, NULL mark, 'HISTORY' status, 0 VERSION FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 9876 student_id, 4597 course_id, 'Institutional' enrollment_type, 99 mark, 'ACTIVE' status, 1 VERSION FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 9876 student_id, 4597 course_id, 'Institutional' enrollment_type, NULL mark, 'HISTORY' status, 0 VERSION FROM dual),
  group_enrollments AS (SELECT 4976555 group_id, 1234 student_id, 5678 course_id, 'Mandatory2' enrollment_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 6399875 group_id, 1234 student_id, 9034 course_id, 'Optional' enrollment_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 6399875 group_id, 9876 student_id, 4597 course_id, 'Institutional' enrollment_type FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables with data in them
SELECT res.student_id,
       res.course_id,
       CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN res.new_enrollment_type
            WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN res.old_enrollment_type
       END enrollment_type,
       res.mark,
       CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN 'ACTIVE'
            WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN 'HISTORY'
       END status,
       CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN res.new_version
            WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN res.old_version
       END VERSION 
FROM   (SELECT ge.student_id,
               ge.course_id,
               ge.enrollment_type new_enrollment_type,
               p.enrollment_type old_enrollment_type,
               p.mark,
               p.status,
               p.version old_version,
               nvl(p.version + 1, 0) new_VERSION
                 -- n.b. this may produce duplicates or unique constraint errors in a concurrent environment
        FROM   group_enrollments ge
               LEFT OUTER JOIN PERFORMANCE p ON ge.student_id = p.student_id
                                                AND ge.course_id = p.course_id
        WHERE  (p.status = 'ACTIVE' OR p.status IS NULL)
        AND    (p.enrollment_type != ge.enrollment_type OR p.enrollment_type IS NULL)) res
        INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 1
                                                    OR (dummy.id = 2 
                                                        AND res.status = 'ACTIVE');

STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID ENROLLMENT_TYPE       MARK STATUS     VERSION
---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ------- ----------
      1234       5678 Mandatory2              70 ACTIVE           3
      1234       9034 Optional                   ACTIVE           0
      1234       5678 Mandatory               70 HISTORY          2
```

This query first of all finds any rows that are brand new (i.e. rows in the group_enrollment table that don't have a row in the performance table) or have a different enrollment_type. These are the rows that need inserting or updating.

Once we know that, we can then join a dummy, 2-row table table such that we'll always join to the first dummy row regardless of whether we need to insert or update, but we'll only join to the second dummy row if we need to update. This means we will only ever have one row for an insert, but two rows for an update.

Then it's an easy matter of outputting the correct values based on the dummy.id (new values for the first dummy row, old values for the second dummy row.

Once we've done that, we know what data needs to be merged into the performance table, so now the merge statement will look something like:

```
merge into performance tgt
  using (SELECT res.student_id,
                res.course_id,
                CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN res.new_enrollment_type
                     WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN res.old_enrollment_type
                END enrollment_type,
                res.mark,
                CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN 'ACTIVE'
                     WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN 'HISTORY'
                END status,
                CASE WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN res.new_version
                     WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN res.old_version
                END VERSION 
         FROM   (SELECT ge.student_id,
                        ge.course_id,
                        ge.enrollment_type new_enrollment_type,
                        p.enrollment_type old_enrollment_type,
                        p.mark,
                        p.status,
                        p.version old_version,
                        nvl(p.version + 1, 0) new_VERSION
                          -- n.b. this may produce duplicates or unique constraint errors in a concurrent environment
                 FROM   group_enrollments ge
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN PERFORMANCE p ON ge.student_id = p.student_id
                                                         AND ge.course_id = p.course_id
                 WHERE  (p.status = 'ACTIVE' OR p.status IS NULL)
                 AND    (p.enrollment_type != ge.enrollment_type OR p.enrollment_type IS NULL)) res
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                             SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 1
                                                             OR (dummy.id = 2 
                                                                 AND res.status = 'ACTIVE')) src
    ON (tgt.student_id = src.student_id AND tgt.course_id = src.course_id AND tgt.status = src.status)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.enrollment_type = src.enrollment_type,
             tgt.version = src.version
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.student_id, tgt.course_id, tgt.enrollment_type, tgt.mark, tgt.status, tgt.version)
  VALUES (src.student_id, src.course_id, src.enrollment_type, src.mark, src.status, src.version);
```

---

For clarification purposes, here's a very simple example of the conditional duplication of rows (we could also call it a partial cross join, since all rows in one table are joined to at least one row in the other):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 100 ID, NULL status FROM dual UNION ALL -- expect only one row
                     SELECT 101 ID, 'A' status FROM dual UNION ALL -- expect two rows
                     SELECT 102 ID, 'B' status FROM dual -- expect only one row
                    )
SELECT dummy.id dummy_row_id,
       sd.id,
       sd.status
FROM   sample_data sd
       INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 1
                                                   OR (dummy.id = 2 
                                                       AND sd.status = 'A')
ORDER BY sd.id, dummy.id;

DUMMY_ROW_ID         ID STATUS
------------ ---------- ------
           1        100 
           1        101 A
           2        101 A
           1        102 B
```

You can see that for the id=101 row from the sample_data "table", we have two rows, but the other two ids only have one row each.

Hopefully that clarifies things for you?

Comment: I'm still new to SQL, so I don't think I got your point here.
How is this creating a new row when it finds one that matches?

Comment: Do you see the dummy subquery that I'm INNER JOINing the res subquery to? That's a two row resultset. The join condition `dummy.id = 1` ensures that we will always join the first row from the dummy subquery to every single row in the res subquery. The `or (dummy.id = 2 and res.status = 'ACTIVE')` condition means we only join the 2nd dummy row if the res.status = 'ACTIVE'. The res.status column is only populated if we have a row for that student_id and course_id in the performance table already, so we know we need to have two rows for that - the updated row and the historical row. Make sense?

Comment: I've also added a simpler example to the end of my answer, to hopefully clear things up a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. In what part of the code are we actually inserting the row? The merge still results in when matched update (existing row) and when not matched insert, right? Is the dummy subquery modifying the origin so that the rows won't match and another gets inserted?
Sorry for the ignorant questions, but I'm getting really confused... by the way, I haven't specified because I thought it would have made it easier, but I'm working on a view where the status of all the rows is ACTIVE.

Comment: Ok, if you look at the results of my first query, you can see that for student_id = 1234 and course_id = 5678, we have two rows produced - one active with vesrsion 3 and the new enrollment_type, the other is history, with version 2 and the old enrollment_type. You can also see that the row in the performance "table" for that student and course id and version = 2 has the old enrollment_type and is active. So, the merge does a join on student_id, course_id and status (and I assume only one ACTIVE row per student+course).

Comment: We can see that the src subquery produces two rows (versions 2 (historic) and 3 (active)). The version 3 row will match to the existing version 2 row in the performance table (they both have a status of active, remember) so we'll update the version 2 row in the performance table and set the version to 3 and it's enrollment_type to the new one, but the version 2 row doesn't match - therefore we need to insert it. Does that make sense? If it doesn't, try creating some test tables, insert some sample data and have a play around with the query and merge statements to see what each does.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it and managed to make it work! The query is a bit heavy (it takes up to 3 minutes when I run it on my db), but it shouldn't be a problem since it will run once a day during nighttime. I really can't thank you enough, it was a brilliant solution for my problem and a good occasion to learn more about SQL as well!

Comment: Oh right: it would work if I used the subquery to create a view and use that to do the merge, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could create a view, yes - that would simplify the merge statement, but it most likely won't impact the performance. Depending on how many rows are in your tables, 3 mins isn't necessarily a long time

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use a view just to avoid putting 60 lines of SQL in the application code, so that it will be easier to manage. 
I know, we're talking about 1 million+ rows, I'm just not used to queries that take that long :)

Comment: You might find it speeds things up a bit to have a multi-column index on the performance table on columns (student_id, course_id, status), if you don't already have such an index.